# jquery select html elements when using React Framework

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I'm the admin of a group on facebook and whenever someone enters that group I can send a welcome message to them. I'm trying to create a script to automate that for me and automatically welcome users since there're a lot of people coming in and I can't stop my daily tasks to this manually.

The problem: I can't interact with Facebook html through chrome console like other pages because they use a [framework called React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), which creates some sort of "virtual DOM".

While trying to use chrome console to select an element called **$('#u_jsonp_50_7');** for instance, I get this message:

```
Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","#u_jsonp_50_7"]]]>
```

So that's the question: how can I interact with facebook html elements using jquery while they're using this virtual dom framework? I'm trying to do that by either using Tampermonkey chrome extension or even creating my own extension.

Hope someone can help and provide any ideas on how to do that.

Comment: are you sure that people want that? i would rather just pin a welcome post instead. not sure if what you want to do is even allowed on facebook.

Comment: Try comparing page html before and after the event in element inspector, or text editor, or online diff for html if there is one. Then you'll be able to detect it using a periodic check or MutationObserver. Or you can try using facebook API (I know nothing about it).

Comment: @luschn I already have a welcome message pinned but a lot of people doesn't pay attention to it. They feel more comfortable when receiving a "direct" message sent only to them and I even reinstate them to check the pinned post. I'm not sure what do you mean by "not sure if what you want to do is even allowed on facebook", the welcome field is supplied by facebook itself, I just want to automate the process

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't understad much since I'm on early stages of programming, sorry for the rookie questions :/ I tried to check the source code but the elements in there are inside comments, which I guess is a resource from react and the reason why I can't select them. When I inspect the page they seem fine like regular html, but I can't select them using the console. Can you give me more details on how to detect this changes or more insights on how to use this MutationObserver?